# Simple statement about the cantor set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Struggling to understand the cantor set i found [this](http://www.math.utah.edu/~erin/32103/Cantor.pdf).

It's really helpful but at the very start when the cantor set is defined it is stated that:

"$A_k$ is a union of $2^k$ closed intervals of length $3^{-k}$"

without proof.
I tried to prove it by induction but got bogged down in silly details.

Could you show me how it can be neatly proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by induction on $k$. For $k=0$, we have $[0,1]$.

Suppose that for $k$ it holds, then $A_k$ is the union of $2^k$ closed intervals, each of length $3^{-k}$. Then $A_{k+1}$ is the set generated by removing the (open) middle third of each of these intervals, the remainder is two (closed) intervals of exactly $\frac13$ of the length. So we have $2\cdot2^k$ closed intervals, each of length $\frac13\cdot3^{-k}=3^{-(k+1)}$, as wanted.

Comment: So in that case you define $A_{k+1}$ to be $A_k$ with the middle third of every interval removed? In munkres it's defined a bit differently.

Comment: You linked to a pdf file. I took that definition from there.